# Not outputting a heading if a search: within Grid has no results

Tags: grid

We are using Grid to manage resources / and downloads on a site. We need to pull together resources from a number of different entries, based on segment. We use a search within Grid on a Select Dropdown to output the appropriate resource.

This is working as expected, but we cannot find a way to not output the `<h2>` and `<ul>` if the search: within Grid has no results. If we use {limit="1"} on {exp:channel_entries} it won't work, as the entry it recalls may or may not have the appropriate resource in the Grid Select Dropdown.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
<h2> Waste Management Group {segment_2}</h2>
<ul class="no-style-list resources">
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="groups"
    disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" 
    dynamic="no" 
    status="open"
    cache="yes" 
    refresh="30"
}
{group_resources search:resource_type="{segment_2}"}
    <li>
        <a class="{group_resources:resource_file}{extension}{/group_resources:resource_file} {group_resources:resource_type}" href="{group_resources:resource_link}{group_resources:resource_file}" target="_blank">
            {group_resources:resource_title} {group_resources:resource_file}</a>({exp:filesize_format dec="0"}{file_size}{/exp:filesize_format} {extension}){/group_resources:resource_file}

    </li>
{/group_resources}
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditionals in the Grid loop to conditionally output the heading and `<ul>` tags:

```
{group_resources search:resource_type="{segment_2}"}
{if group_resources:count == 1}
<h2> Waste Management Group {segment_2}</h2>
<ul class="no-style-list resources">
{/if>    
    <li>
        <a class="{group_resources:resource_file}{extension}{/group_resources:resource_file} {group_resources:resource_type}" href="{group_resources:resource_link}{group_resources:resource_file}" target="_blank">
            {group_resources:resource_title} {group_resources:resource_file}</a>({exp:filesize_format dec="0"}{file_size}{/exp:filesize_format} {extension}){/group_resources:resource_file}

    </li>
{if group_resources:count == group_resources:field_total_rows}
</ul>
{/if}
{/group_resources}
```

Comment: Thx Jeremy. That still outputs the <h2> and <ul> once for each entry that includes at least one row in the Grid. It closes each <ul> for each output as well.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a no_results conditional for the grid field. I'm not sure if that exists.

Comment: Thx Jeremy, I don't think it does. I ended up rebuilding the resources section of the site using Assets.